# Are there limits to Selenium grid

Tags: selenium, grid, browser-automation

I got a requirement from my client to implement Selenium grid. Requirement details as follows:

- Number of nodes running concurrent test cases: 200-250
- 3 Selenium nodes per machine (~ 66 to 85 machines running the 200-250 nodes)
- Every machine is a Windows machine and has 8GB RAM
- The test cases are long-running in nature. about 10000 steps per test case. (click, type etc are considered to be the test steps)
- The option of using grid services from providers like browserstack is ruled out. I will have to do the grid setup locally.

I am looking for answers for questions like, Has anyone tried grid setup with such level of complexity? Are there any limitations of Selenium to support such large setup? Would there be performance impact due to excessive context switches between threads? What problems should I be prepared to face?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: 85 machines for automation? Space Age!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems possible to me.  Some things to consider:

1. Long running tests with many steps should be broken down into
   smaller test units.

   2. Each grid node, if they have 8GB of ram and dual-proc, should be able to handle up to 10+ browsers, not just 3.
   3. If the tests are simple, you could use PhantomJS 2.x headless browser and get more speed and throughput out of your tests.   This
      is especially useful if the version of the browser your testing with
      doesn't much matter, such as with verification tests.  Regression
      tests, on the other hand, need specific browser versions to verify
      regressions caused by code.
   4. I would say that a grid hub with many nodes on it , should be able to handle 50+ threads at a level of 8gb and dual proc.  So, for
      each 50 threads you would want 5 nodes and 1 hub.

Thats just some thoughts...